# Problem Installing Kernel version 5.5.0

Tags: kernel, dpkg

I use Ubuntu 20.04 running with Kernel version 5.7.0.
I want to run older version of Kernel (5.5.0) and so was downloading the packages:

```
cd /tmp/

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5/linux-headers-5.5.0-050500_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_all.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5/linux-headers-5.5.0-050500-generic_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_amd64.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5/linux-image-unsigned-5.5.0-050500-generic_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_amd64.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5/linux-modules-5.5.0-050500-lowlatency_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**Unfortunately I wasn't able to install this kernel version and got some errors with dpkg:**

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-5.5.0-050500-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-modules-5.5.0-050500-lowlatency (5.5.0-050500.202001262030) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-unsigned-5.5.0-050500-generic
```

Any help please?

---

Thanks for you answers, sorry but I am very new to Linux!
Shall I download only:

```
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5/linux-headers-5.5.0-050500_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_all.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5/linux-headers-5.5.0-050500-generic_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_amd64.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5/linux-image-unsigned-5.5.0-050500-generic_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_amd64.deb
```

and then

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

?

Comment: Why are you installing lowlatency modules with a generic kernel?

Comment: and `wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5/linux-modules-5.5.0-050500-generic_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_amd64.deb`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade Kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80943/how-to-downgrade-kernel)

Comment: I managed to downgrade the version, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are installing `lowlatency` modules with a `generic` kernel.

It won't install this way. You need to download all `generic`, or `lowlatency` packages.