# GNU/Linux Ubuntu 20.04.1 - linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic - linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic breaks AMDGPU drivers

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, amdgpu

I have the same problem on two computers.

Latest kernel pushed in the updates - linux-headers-5.4.56-generic breaks AMDGPU drivers compilation.

amdgpu-dkms failed each time. If i rollback to previous kernel, it compiles properly.

Am i missing something? Does AMDGPU not support this kernel version?

Comment: I have the same problem with `rock-dkms`

Comment: This kernel was removed from the repos yesterday; maybe this is why. I was wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news is even AMD has acknowledged the issue, they even added the problem in their release notes of their latest GNU/Linux drivers, they advised to do not upgrade to this kernel as AMDGPU needs amdgpu-dkms in order to work properly. They are working with the GNU/Linux Ubuntu devs to understand what happened and hopefully fix the issue in the near future. More info here in the known issues section: https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-45

Comment: Looks like kernel version 5.4.0-58 fixed the issue! Had it installed through the Livepatch service. Good job, Ubuntu devs!

Comment: I have the 5.4.0-58 kernel and the `amdgpu-pro` driver ver 20.45 still can't be compiled - a missed `pci_platform_rom` function declaration. AMD needs to fix that

Comment: @HEKTO I guess your only option for now is to downgrade the kernel to 5.4.0-54, then. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/a/80952/1074958) might help (even though it's pretty old). The package name to install is `linux-image-5.4.0-54-generic`

Comment: What about those of us still on Ubuntu 18.04? Has AMD officially dropped support for Bionic?

Answer (score 0):

had problems with this kernel version as well on Ubuntu 20.04.1 today, especifically related to notebook's lid triggered suspension, just issued here: [Ubuntu 20.04 does not wake up properly after lid is closed with Linux Kernel 5.4.0.56 (Report an issue)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297595/ubuntu-20-04-does-not-wake-up-properly-after-lid-is-closed-with-linux-kernel-5-4)

Hope this get worked out soon. For now I would recommend you to use version 5.4.0.54 for the kernel, it worked for me at least. Just a note, my problem ocurred on a laptop with Intel integrated graphics card.