# Ubuntu 20.04 does not wake up properly after lid is closed with Linux Kernel 5.4.0.56 (Report an issue)

Tags: kernel, suspend, laptop

Since today Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS stopped waking up after being suspended by the closing of my laptop's lid, just showing a blank screen. I've tried lots of differents solutions, from modifying some GRUB arguments values to changing lid behavior on systemd's logind.conf file, but none of them seemed to work.

Then I remembered that I updated Linux kernel version 5.4.0.56 earlier today, so I checked to see if the same problem ocurred with version 5.4.0.54. And well, it didn't, with version 5.4.0.54 suspension seeming to work properly still, given that the notebook woken up correctly and that I was able to have access to my laptop again after logging in.

For that I ask how could I report a Linux Kernel issue to its developers, because I'm quite convinced that this a kernel related issue, given that changing the kernel version used solved this issue.

Comment: You can report a bug to LaunchPad.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug  I believe it would be `ubuntu-bug linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic` to file the bug.

Comment: Sorry, it would be `ubuntu-bug linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic` to file the bug for the kernel, not the headers file.  My bad!

Comment: Thanks man! I'll try to report this bug as soon as I can.