# Can't install rock-dkms on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, kernel, amdgpu

I got the following error when trying to install the `rock-dkms` KFD driver for AMD ROCm:

```
$ sudo apt install rock-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  rock-dkms-firmware
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  rock-dkms rock-dkms-firmware
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/11.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 243 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Selecting previously unselected package rock-dkms-firmware.
(Reading database ... 304692 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../rock-dkms-firmware_1%3a3.10-27_all.deb ...
Unpacking rock-dkms-firmware (1:3.10-27) ...
Setting up rock-dkms-firmware (1:3.10-27) ...
Selecting previously unselected package rock-dkms.
(Reading database ... 305096 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../rock-dkms_1%3a3.10-27_all.deb ...
Unpacking rock-dkms (1:3.10-27) ...
Setting up rock-dkms (1:3.10-27) ...
Loading new amdgpu-3.10-27 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-56-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-56-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rock-dkms-firmware.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-56-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/3.10-27/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rock-dkms (--configure):
 installed rock-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rock-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/wyphan/99653d23647008ee63a9bbe778244314) are the contents of `/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/3.10-27/build/make.log`.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64. There are two GPUs installed: AMD Radeon RX Vega 64 and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6 GB.

```
$ uname -a
Linux basecamp 5.4.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 23 19:20:19 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ lspci -v | grep VGA
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Vega 10 XL/XT [Radeon RX Vega 56/64] (rev c1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
0b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297356/gnu-linux-ubuntu-20-04-1-linux-image-5-4-0-56-generic-linux-headers-5-4-0-56/

Comment: The module is incompatible with the kernel.

Comment: The same error (the 'pci_platform_rom' declaration missed) when installing the `amdgpu-pro` driver Ver. 20.45 into Ubuntu kernel 5.4.0-58.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try reverting to an older kernel .

Comment: Or upgrading to 5.4.0-58, where it's fixed.